# do you use getters or make http get to retrieve data on mounted? Vue 3 and Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, store

I have any data in list:

```
<ul> 
  <li v-for="data in allData" :key="data">
    {{ data.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

very simple example but i want to retrieve data from vuex no from component..

```
mounted() { 
  axios.get("endpoint")
    .then(res => { 
      this.allData = res.data;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    }); 
}
```

This is work but i think i can better to retrieve data from vuex..

I have function in `action.js` file

```
[GET_COMPETITOR_ACTION_DATA](context) { 
  axiosinstance.get('competitors').then(res => {
    console.log('res mu' , res); 
    context.commit(GET_COMPETITOR_MUTATION_DATA, res.data); 
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

I also have a function in getters.js

```
[GET_COMPETITOR](state){ 
  return state.competitor;
}
```

in `mutations.js` i have:

```
[GET_COMPETITOR_MUTATION_DATA](state,payload){ 
  payload.map(allD => state.competitor.push(allD)); 
}
```

Right now in components:

WHen try

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters("competitor", {
    competitor: GET_COMPETITOR
  })
```

and use:

```
<ul> 
  <li v-for="data in competitor" :key="data">
    {{ data.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

no work.

when try:

```
...mapActions("competitor", {
  allDataCompetitorData: GET_COMPETITOR_ACTION_DATA
}),

<ul> 
  <li v-for="data in allDataCompetitorData" :key="data">
    {{ data.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also no work..

My question ->

**How best to retrieve data from the store for this get load on the mounted or created?**

And

**Why don't my attempts work?**

Comment: "no work" is for many reasons. You can't iterate allDataCompetitorData with v-for because an action is a function. And you don't call it anywhere (you shouldn't do this in a template any way). GET_COMPETITOR_ACTION_DATA doesn't return a promise. GET_COMPETITOR_MUTATION_DATA doesn't mutate anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wait for response :

```
async mounted() { 
  await this.allDataCompetitorData()
}
```

then in template use getter:

```
<ul> 
  <li v-for="data in competitor" :key="data">
    {{ data.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not help me ...

Comment: Hey mate, doesn't work or?

Comment: If you use vuex persistent state you can also check in mounted if there is data in state so you don't make axios call again

Comment: Why use mounted this.allDataCompetiotrData() when set in v-for competitor ?

Comment: You get data from API with actions, and get data from vuex/show data in template with getters

Comment: ne radi brate, no work friend ... when i console.log getters     [GET_COMPETITOR](state){ 
        console.log(state)
        return state.competitor;
    } 

i got getters is empty ?

Comment: Ček da nađem čekić :)) try to change mutation to something like; `[GET_COMPETITOR_MUTATION_DATA](state, payload) => (state.competitor= payload),`

Comment: And try to change your action to something like: `async [GET_COMPETITOR_ACTION_DATA]({ commit }) {
    const response = await axios.get(URL);
    commit('GET_COMPETITOR_MUTATION_DATA', response.data);
  },`

Comment: ima neku muku... I don;t know what is but no work

Comment: Woork right now...what is problem here was be ?

Comment: Vote up for neighbors...  can you explain me what is problem here ? with async and await ? Big regards from nbgd

Comment: You are welcome :) your action and mutation was wrong and you need to use async and await cose you get promises from axios response. Uživaj big regards from old bg :))